# Ionic 4 platform add android error code ENOLOCAL

Tags: android, angular, cordova, ionic-framework

I removed my android platform on my ionic project and tried to re-install it but I keep receiving `npm ERR! code ENOLOCAL` . here is the error when I type `platform add android`:

```
(node:3880) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: CordovaError: Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
npm ERR! code ENOLOCAL
npm ERR! Could not install from "android" as it does not contain a package.json file.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\RMT016\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2018-09-26T08_08_46_485Z-debug.log
    at C:\Users\RMT016\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\cordova-fetch\index.js:105:29
    at _rejected (C:\Users\RMT016\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\q\q.js:864:24)
    at C:\Users\RMT016\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\q\q.js:890:30
    at Promise.when (C:\Users\RMT016\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\q\q.js:1142:31)
    at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (C:\Users\RMT016\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\q\q.js:808:41)
    at C:\Users\RMT016\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\q\q.js:624:44
    at runSingle (C:\Users\RMT016\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\q\q.js:137:13)
    at flush (C:\Users\RMT016\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\q\q.js:125:13)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:131:7)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:180:9)
(node:3880) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:3880) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate
the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

I tried removing and adding the platform, also removing and adding the node_modules but still get the same error. 
My Cordova version is 8.0 .
anybody knows how to solve this?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

there was and Android folder created in the root directory (not the platforms directory), after removing this folder the command worked again.

Comment: I had ran the capacitor command `npx cap add android` which had created "android" directory in the root. Just renamed it to android_cap and reran the command `cordova platform add android` and it worked perfect. Thanks @nimzz

Comment: Yes it doesn't play nice with Capacitor.  Renaming worked for me.

Answer (score 3):

Remove the Android folder from the project directory

Answer (score 0):

I accidentiall run the capacitor command instead of using cordova. After removing the android forlder that was created with the capacitor command it worked again.